# When calculating the red shift of a star, what does the value mean?

Tags: space-expansion

Is red shift (z) given as a velocity, or a constant? If it's a constant, what does the given value mean?

Comment: Have you looked on the [Wikipedia entry on redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift)?

Answer (score 2):

Red shift does not have units so it is not a velocity, 
but can be converted to one using the equation $v = zc$. Instead, redshift is given as the "error" in the wavelength.

$$\frac{\lambda_{measured} - \lambda_{expected}}{\lambda_{measured}}=z$$

This can change but with no units you can consider redshift/blueshift a constant.

Comment: Note that the equation $v = zc$ is only valid for small (non-relativistic) velocities.